# Como consumir um metodo multipart form-data com metodo void

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, node.js, rest

Como consumir um metodo *multipart/form-data* de um webservice feito em java, por ajax ou jquery?

Abaixo deixo como esta o metodo:

JAVA:

```
@POST
    @Path("/aprovarCompra")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public void aprovarCompra(@FormParam("nrCompra") Long nrCompra,
            @FormParam("usuario") String usuario) {
//aqui faco as validacoes conecto ao banco e aprovo a compra
}
```

O front end esta em nodeJS (ao qual nao conheco quase nada, e a empresa optou por fazer dessa forma)

O codigo que tenho no front end é o seguinte:

```
$('#aprovar').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"10.0.2.15:7001/ws/resources/Compra/aprovarCompra",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    data:'nrCompra=12345&usuario=usuarioMaster', 
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error:function (){
        alert("error ao aprovar a Compra: "+nrCompra);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi muito bem o problema, mas acredito que não esteja conseguindo ler os parâmetros de entrada do WebService.

Primeira coisa, altere o `contentType` da chamada do Ajax para:

`contentType: "multipart/form-data"`

O que pode ser analisado depois, é verificar a [chamada ao serviço](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading) e "debugar" a requisição do lado do servidor.

Espero que tenho ajudado.

Comment: preciso consumir o webservice aprovando a compra, na pagina web consigo o nrCompra e o usuario.

estou tentando fazer isso via ajax mas se houver outro meio estou aberto a sugestoes.

Comment: a chamada Ajax, chega no servidor?

Comment: nao esta chegando, nao sei o porque um amigo pediu para instalar cors para tentar depois. tambem posso alterar a forma do webservice soh preciso que seja separado os codigos de front e back end

Comment: você chegou a olhar a chamada pelo network da ferramento de desenvolvimento do browser?

Comment: ola heber obrigado pela ajuda, apos instalar o plugins cors no google chrome tudo esta funcionando corretamente.